# Web service call inside onResume() not working properly

Tags: android, retrofit, onresume

I am using `OnResume()` method to call web service every time when I come back to the activity.Everything works fine when app is in foreground, but when app goes to background sometimes works fine but sometimes it is not.below is my code

```
    private void getRetrofit(final String searchstr){
    if(session.getUserRegisterID()==null){
        UserRegid="0";
    }else{
        UserRegid=session.getUserRegisterID();
    }

    ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait ...", "Loading Stores ...", true);
    ringProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);

    Log.e("response", "Execute1");//Up to this code is executed in issue scenario it is not entering into further and no other logs are called.

    serviceApi = ServiceGenerator.createService(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<okhttp3.ResponseBody> call = serviceApi.getStores(new StoreJsonObject(searchstr, SignInActivity.nwLocation.getLatitude()+","+SignInActivity.nwLocation.getLongitude()
            , UserRegid,session.getRadiousName(),1,10,PageName));
    Log.e("response", "Execute2");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<okhttp3.ResponseBody>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<okhttp3.ResponseBody> call, Response<okhttp3.ResponseBody> response) {
            try {
                Log.e("response", "Success");
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("response", "Exception");
                e.printStackTrace();
                ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<okhttp3.ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("response", "Failed");
            ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

and my `onResume()` method is

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getRetrofit("");
}
```

Please observe comment at "Log.e("response", "Execute1");" line.

Comment: What exception are you expecting to be thrown from a Log.e?

Comment: i didn't got any exception upto this "Log.e("response", "Execute2");"part code is executing ,I just kept it for my reference upto where the code is being executing.@Anix

Comment: Sure, a simple Log wont throw any exception. The catch block is useless.

Comment: Then What should i do know about the exception?

Comment: If all you're doing is a Log.e then remove your try catch block.

Comment: Actually it is not going into success part of the above code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133639/discussion-between-hari-krishna-and-anix-pasbesoin).

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue and spent almost a day but finally I Tried to Disable Instant Run and issue fixed.

Comment: in the studio you disabeld instant run?

Comment: Yes, Go to File > Setting > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run > Uncheck @Harikrishna